# windows linux timestamping c++ error

Tags: c++, networking, timestamp, endianness

I am trying to write time stamp code to calculate lag by sending time stamps in milliseconds. The server code runs on linux while the client runs on windows:

The function used to obtain the time stamp is as follows:

```
uint64_t TimeStamp() {
    uint64_t ll_now;
#if PLATFORM==PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    FILETIME ft_now; 
    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft_now);
    ll_now = (uint64_t)ft_now.dwLowDateTime + ((uint64_t)(ft_now.dwHighDateTime) << 32LL);
    ll_now -= 116444736000000000LL;
    ll_now /= 10000;
#elif PLATFORM==PLATFORM_LINUX
    timeval end;
    gettimeofday( (timeval*)&end,NULL );
    ll_now=(uint64_t)(end.tv_usec)/1000LL;
    ll_now += ((uint64_t)(end.tv_sec) * 1000LL);
#endif
    return ll_now;
}
```

In the client code, the time stamp is packed for sending as follows:

```
uint64_t tmstamp= TimeStamp();
uint32_t ts_high=((uint32_t)(tmstamp>>32LL));
uint32_t ts_low =((uint32_t)(tmstamp & 0xFFFFFFFFLL));
ts_high=htonl(ts_high);
ts_low=htonl(ts_low);
StdOPacket p;
p<<ts_high<<ts_low;
```

In the server code, the time stamp is unpacked when received as follows:

```
uint32_t ts_high,ts_low;
input>>ts_high>>ts_low;
ts_high=ntohl(ts_high);
ts_low=ntohl(ts_low);
uint64_t sndTS=uint64_t(ts_low)+(uint64_t(ts_high)<<32LL);
uint64_t curTS=TimeStamp();
int64_t dif=(int64_t)curTS-(int64_t)sndTS;
std::cout<<"current timestamp: "<<curTS<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"send timestamp: "<<sndTS<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"dif: "<<dif<<std::endl;
```

However, when I run the program, the difference is calculated to be approximately -1000(ms), which defies the laws of time?

Note: StdOPacket simply copies given data pointers into a buffer, and StdIPacket copies data from a buffer to a given reference.

EDIT:

Platform definition:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define PLATFORM PLATFORM_WINDOWS
#elif defined __linux__
#define PLATFORM PLATFORM_LINUX
#else
#define PLATFORM PLATFORM_UNKOWN
#endif
```

Comment: You can not expect the time of two unsynchronized sources being identical

Comment: How does one go about calculating latency then?

Comment: @joelyboy94: You send your timestap to the server and the server sends the exact same packet back to your client, then you can calculate the difference with another call to `Timestamp()`. Also you need no low/high for milliseconds accuracy, just prune it to a 32 bit unsigned integer before sending (which is good for ~49 days).

Comment: @joelyboy94: Also keep in mind that functions like `gettimeofday()` can fail - so make sure to check its return value.

Comment: @joelyboy94: Another thing: don't use `#if PLATFORM==PLATFORM_WINDOWS` better use `#ifdef _WIN32` (works for x64 too) and `#ifdef __linux__` for Linux. You don't need your own define for it.

Comment: @Thomas So if the latency is calculated from the there-and-back time, does the timestamp actually need to included in the packet sent to the server? And I've added an edit for the platform definition, I forgot to put it in the original.

Comment: @joelyboy94: It's at least the easiest way (otherwise you need to track the packet somehow, as there might be other packets as well).

Answer (score 0):

, of a dummy packetBecause your Server and your client machine system clocks are not synchronized.

You can :

1. Measure a ping (round trip, or RTT, time, from the Server
   machine), in order to use a single clock
2. Synchronize your
   machines clock (depending on the expected accuracy, it could be
   quite hard). See [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) and [PTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol) sync protocols.